# how to connect hive with Superset?

Tags: database, hive, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I want connect hive with superset but I got this error

> An error occurred while creating databases: (configuration_method) Missing data for required field.

My sqlalchemy command is `hive://myhost:10000/default`

I start the hiveserver and hivemetastore before connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Format for connection string of hive should be

```
hive://hive@{hostname}:{port}/{database}
```

Documentation can be found here:

https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/installing-database-drivers